# Symfony2 - Composer could not scan classes inside - ZipArchive:Extracto

Tags: composer-php

Im building a little application with symfony2 everything worked fine and i just did a

```
php composer.phar update
```

Which make the project unable to run , now i got 3 different error that I can't solve .

1 - When i hit the root url "/" of project or "/app_dev.php"

[image]

2- When i run `php composer.phar install --profile` i get this error
[image]

3- When i run `php composer.phar update --profile` i get this error
[image]

**I tried to delete the cache by hand of both symfony and composer , it did absolutly nothing**

Any solution with this terrible package manager ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved , the name canno't exceed 260 Charcters under windows .

Had to change the path of my project to shorten the url .

See github for detail
https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/2712